# Update images in SQL from Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have an issue trying to upload files from Python to my database. I can insert the binary data into the table just fine using `%s`, but when I try to update the record, I am unable to get this to work. Am I doing something wrong?

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x01\x90\x00\x00\x00\xc8\x08\x06\x00\' at line 8`

Now, I know this is because the bytestring contains a `'` so this doesn't work, it excepts, and leaves some security holes open if it were to work:

```
dbc.execute(f"""UPDATE userdata SET 
emailaddr ='{email}',
firstname ='{namee}',
lastname  ='{laste}',
username  ='{usere}',
password  ='{passe}',
phonenum  ='{phone}',
photoimg  ='{u_pho}'
WHERE user_id = '{user_ident}';""")
```

but I'm wondering if I can update a value like this:

```
insertcommand = f"""UPDATE userdata SET (emailaddr,firstname,lastname,username,password,phonenum,photoimg) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) WHERE user_id = '{user_ident}'"""
insertrecord = email,namee,laste,usere,passe,phone,u_pho
dbc.execute(insertcommand,insertrecord)
```

How would I go about updating bytestrings in MySQL with Python?

Comment: Change it to `WHERE user_id = %s` and add `user_ident` to the end of `insertrecord`

Comment: A simple way is, you may just encode that file to `base64` then save that base64 string to your db. But I think this isn't really good practice.

Comment: Still getting an error. ```mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(emailaddr,firstname,lastname,username,password,phonenum,photoimg) VALUES ('Edna' at line 1```

Comment: Yes Dhana! That could work. Thanks for the idea.